# What is an elegant way for calling a custom close-method on each worker-thread in a Java threadpool?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

say I'm using a

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrofthreads);
```

spinning up some work and waiting when it's done.

However I have same Threadlocal objects in the worker-threads which need to be closed when the batch is done. 
Therefore, I would like to be able to call a custom close-method on all worker-threads created by the threadpool.

What would be the most elegant way to do that?

Right now as a hack I'm using:

```
for(int i =0 ; i<20; i++){ //make sure to touch all threads with 20 runs..
   ex.execute(new Runnable(){
 public void run(){
   tearDownThreadLocals();
 }
   });
}  
ex.shutdown();
```

but that doesn't look particulary robust to me ;-)

Thanks
GJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int, ThreadFactory)` to pass a `ThreadFactory`, something like this:

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrofthreads, 
    new ThreadFactory() {
        public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
            return new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        r.run();
                    } finally {
                        tearDownThreadLocals();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:** Just noticed that `Executors` already has a method that accepts a `ThreadFactory`, so no need to create `ThreadPoolExecutor` explicitly.

Comment: Would you want to put: try { r.run(); } finally { tearDownThreadLocals(); } to ensure its always called regardless of how run works out?